# jruby 1.5.1, warning: already initialized constant Deprecate

Tags: ruby, jruby

Using jruby 1.5.1

In a pretty simple cronjob that uses gems:

- dbi
- dbd-jdbc
- jdbc-mysql

It also uses a pure Java JDBC driver in a jar, jtds-1.2.5.jar

Every time I run it, I get this in STDERR (which is annoying my cronjob monitoring utilty which thinks anything on stderr may be a problem)

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5.1/gems/deprecated-2.0.1/lib/deprecated.rb:199 warning: already initialized constant Deprecate
```

?? Any ideas? What's going on, what can I do about it?  Not sure which of these gems depends on 'deprecated' library or what version, any easy way to find out?

Ah, okay, figured it out:

```
[rochkind@catalyst pull_reserves]$ gem dependency dbi
Gem dbi-0.4.5
  deprecated (= 2.0.1)
```

But 0.4.5 is the most recent version of 'dbi', and it is locked to 2.0.1 of 'deprecated'.  There is a more recent 3.0.0 version of deprecated.

Okay... not sure what my question is now, except if anyone can figure out more about what's going on, and what my actual options are. I guess report as an issue to 'dbi' gem, hoping it's got some maintainers who care, I dunno.

**more update**: Okay, and there's already an issue filed for this, from August. https://github.com/erikh/ruby-dbi/pull/8  Looks like the gem is not very maintained. sigh. sometimes ruby community really frustrates me.

Comment: If you're using JDBC and JRuby anyway, you could bypass dbi and just call JDBC directly from JRuby.

Comment: @theglauber: can I do that with ActiveRecord?  'dbi' was how I thought to use activerecord with jdbc in jruby -- is there a better way? And actually I specifically need Sybase support, maybe that was how i ended up with dbi?

Comment: Probably not. I haven't used activerecord so i can't say for sure, but i did a quick check of its documentation and it says it has builtin support for MySQL using a pure-ruby driver. That may work better for you than dbd-jdbc, or at least it's something to try. Another avenue of investigation is trying jruby 1.6.6 which was released a couple days ago. Good luck! (Although all of this is probably overkill if all you need to do is silence that error message; perhaps you could edit the deprecated module, or cheat by using grep or other utility to discard that particular message).

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you need:

[Suppress Warnings From Ruby](https://mentalized.net/journal/2010/04/02/suppress-warnings-from-ruby/)

A comment there mentions the [Rails method to silence warnings](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-silence_warnings), but I don't think you're using Rails.

EDIT: I found slightly cleaner code here:
https://mislav.net/2011/06/ruby-verbose-mode/

EDIT: Note: A commenter below seems to disagree with the blog entry mentioned above. I'm not expressing agreement or disagreement with the blog entry and I'm not opinionating on the goodness or badness of Ruby's verbose mode, merely crediting the author for the slightly cleaner code I found there.

I think this is what you'd do:

```
module Kernel
def silence_warnings
    with_warnings(nil) { yield }
end

def with_warnings(flag)
    old_verbose, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, flag
    yield
ensure
    $VERBOSE = old_verbose
end
end unless Kernel.respond_to? :silence_warnings


# assuming the warning is being generated when the dbi module is loaded...
silence_warnings { require 'dbi' }
```

Comment: Please don't link to Mislav's post about verbose mode without linking to Avdi Grimm's debunking of that article.

Comment: Don't know where that is, could you help me find it?